# having "typedef void FuncCharPtr" in one class how to feed function that uses that typedef with non static functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, typedef

So I have a class like:

```
class IGraphElement{

    // We should define prototype of functions that will be subscribers to our data
    typedef void FuncCharPtr(char*, int) ;

public:
    // Function for adding subscribers functions
    void Add(FuncCharPtr* f)
    {
            //...
    }
 };
```

and another class like

```
#include "IGraphElement.h"

class  simpleRendererGraphElement : public IGraphElement
{
  public:
    IGraphElement* charGenerator;
    // we owerrite init
    void Init(IGraphElement* CharGenerator)
    {
        charGenerator = CharGenerator;
        //we can to subscribe some function to our data generator
        charGenerator->Add(renderCastedData); // and here we receive C3867 
    }
    void renderCastedData(char* castedChar, int castedCharLength) //  our event system receives functions declared like void FuncCharPtr(char*, int) ;
    { }
};
```

why we get error C3867 and how to fix it not making functions static?

Comment: `FuncCharPtr` is a misnomer:  it isn't a pointer type at all, it's a function type.  A pointer type would look like `typedef void (*FuncCharPtr)(char*, int);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderCastedData` is a nonstatic member function.  Its type is

```
void (simpleRendererGraphElement::*)(char*, int)
```

In order to call it, you need to have an instance of `simpleRendererGraphElement` for the `this` parameter.  There are lots of solutions to this problem.  One option would be to make `Add` a function template that takes anything that can be called with a `char*` and an `int` parameter:

```
template <typename Function>
void Add(Function f)
```

then you can write a function object to wrap the call:

```
struct RenderCastedDataFunctor
{
    simpleRendererGraphElement* obj_;

    RenderCastedDataFunctor(simpleRendererGraphElement* obj)
        : obj_(obj) { }

    void operator()(char* castedChar, int castedCharLength)
    {
        obj_->renderCastedData(castedChar, castedCharLength);
    }
};
```

and from your `Init` function you can call

```
charGenerator->Add(RenderCastedDataFunctor(this));
```

(The `bind` and `function` libraries from Boost, C++ TR1, and C++0x provide a generalized form of this pattern, allowing you to bind arguments to any callable entity and store those bound callable entities for later use.  This particular approach here is just a dumbed down version that should work without any extra or possibly not supported libraries.)

Comment: Wouldn't it work with out RenderCastedDataFunctor after making Add a template ? And can we specify our template function inputs?

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void FuncCharPtr(char*, int) ;
```

First of all, the above should be this,

```
typedef void (*FuncCharPtr)(char*, int) ;
```

---

Second, `renderCastedData` is not a function pointer; it's member-function pointer. So there is a difference. It's type is `void (simpleRendererGraphElement::*)(char*, int);`, not the above type!

Comment: I am not down voter - I voted up. And I have a question - how to make typedef be a template so that any pointer type that takes (char*, int) arguments would be "Addable"?

Comment: @Kabumbus: you cannot write generic typedef. it's not allowed. but don't worry, you've better solution: you can write generic functor to achieve the same!

Comment: @Kabumbus: in your other topic, `RenderCastedDataFunctor` is better than this or maybe I'll expain this tomorrow, as right now I'm going to sleep; it's already 2:45 AM here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842472/can-we-turn-such-structure-into-typed-class-function/4842528#4842528

Answer (score 1):

A member function is not a regular function, and can't be assigned to a regular function pointer.

Use static member function, if `renderCastedData` needn't to be binded to any class instance.

If `renderCastedData` must be binded to a class instance, let `IGraphElement::Add` accept a member function pointer and a pointer to the class.

boost::function and boost::bind is also a good choice for the problem, they provide much more flexbility, but sometimes it can be a little slower.