# Can we turn such structure into typed class/function?

Tags: c++, oop, events, templates, function-pointers

So in structure like

```
struct RenderCastedDataFunctor
{
    simpleRendererGraphElement* obj_;

    RenderCastedDataFunctor(simpleRendererGraphElement* obj)
        : obj_(obj) { }

    void operator()(char* castedChar, int castedCharLength)
    {
        obj_->renderCastedData(castedChar, castedCharLength);
    }
};
```

can we turn simpleRendererGraphElement* into abstract type and make its function name we use in structure (`renderCastedData`) abstract too?

So I have a function inside `charGenerator` class

```
template <typename Function>
void AddSubscriberToGeneratedData(Function f)
```

I want to pass to it functions from different classes of `type void (differentClass::*)(char*, int)`

With that structure inside some simpleRendererGraphElement I can subscribe function called `renderCastedData` to data with
`charGenerator->AddSubscriberToGeneratedData(RenderCastedDataFunctor(this));`
I want to have a way to be capable to pass abstract class function that takes `char*` and `int` to `AddSubscriberToGeneratedData`. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we turn
>   simpleRendererGraphElement* into
>   abstract type and make its function
>   name we use in structure
>   (renderCastedData) abstract too?

Very very good idea. You should do this. Make the class abstract by making it's functions `virtual`, and then define a concrete class (deriving from this abstract class) which implements the virtual functions. That would be a better design!

And the rest seems already fine. You don't have to do anything, as you're doing this:

```
AddSubscriberToGeneratedData(RenderCastedDataFunctor(this));
```

I suppose, here `this` represents the pointer to an instance of the concrete class. If so, then that should work!

---

EDIT:

> I understand how good this Idea is but
>   I do not get how to implement it. that
>   is why I am asking.

Alright. Here is an example:

```
class AbstractGraphElement
{
  public:
    virtual void RenderCastedData(char* castedChar, int castedCharLength) = 0;
};
```

This is your abstract class, and `RenderCastedData` is a pure virtual function. Now you need to define a concrete class which must define  `RenderCastedData` function. So here it is:

```
class SimpleGraphElement : public AbstractGraphElement
{
  public:
    virtual void RenderCastedData(char* castedChar, int castedCharLength)
    {
        //function body - define it yourself
    }
};
```

Done!

Now what you need to do is this. Modify `RenderCastedDataFunctor` as follows:

```
struct RenderCastedDataFunctor
{
    AbstractGraphElement* m_graphElement;

    RenderCastedDataFunctor(AbstractGraphElement* graphElement)
        : m_graphElement(graphElement) { }

    void operator()(char* castedChar, int castedCharLength)
    {
        m_graphElement->RenderCastedData(castedChar, castedCharLength);
    }
};
```

Then add subscriber,

```
AbstractGraphElement *pGraphElement = new SimpleGraphElement();
AddSubscriberToGeneratedData(RenderCastedDataFunctor(pGraphElement));
```

I think it gave your some idea, right? The important point is : use pointer of type `AbstractGraphElement` but initialize this pointer with `SimpleGraphElement`. I think, you should read about virtual functions, and runtime polymorphism. That would help you a lot.

Comment: I understand how good this Idea is but I do not get how to implement it. that is why I am asking.